# Play 2.2.1 -Making async call in Filter

Tags: playframework, scala-2.10

I'm storing a token in redis and using the [redis non-blocking lib](https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis-nb) to fetch it .   This library returns a Future[Option[String]] for the get api call that I am using. I can't figure out how to handle this in the flow while keeping it async.  I can get it working if I  introduce a blocking call using Await.result like so -

```
object TokenFilter extends Filter {
  def apply(nextFilter: (RequestHeader) => Future[SimpleResult])
           (requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {    
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global     
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("redis-Client")
    implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher
    implicit val timeout = AkkaTimeout(2 seconds)

    val accesstoken: Future[Option[String]] = RedisClientFactory.getRedisClient().get("key11")

    val result = Await.result(accesstoken, 2 second)
    result match {
      case Some(v) =>
        Logger.info("success with value " + v)
        nextFilter(requestHeader)
      case None =>
          Logger.info("failure with None ")
          Future.successful(Results.Forbidden)        
   }

  }       
}
```

I seem to be missing some basic concept here. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. I need to call nextFilter(requestHeader) for success else return Results.Forbidden.

Here is some of my attempt that doesn't type check.

```
    accesstoken map{ result =>
      result match {
          case Some(v) =>
            Logger.info("success with value " + v)
            nextFilter(requestHeader)   //won't type check
          case None =>
              Logger.info("failure with None ")
              Results.Forbidden
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as I got the answer from play thread and hitting myself in the head for not thinking about it. flatMap is the answer.  Easiest way to remember is to use map to transform a content within a container. flatMap to get it out of the container.